# Xcode 9 beta new build system fails with "unable to build node" error

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode9-beta

It seems like Xcode 9 beta does not like "~ipad" in filenames for .xib files. When selecting the new build system (for a project, that is compiling successfully with the old build system), it errors out with:

> unable to build node:
>   '/Users/dev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/proj-aiatvieseyfwjkfqncikqcohpdsn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/proj.app/Controller~ipad.nib'
>   (node is produced by multiple commands; e.g.,
>   'adf8a93da84709e14beaf35ec6d6d21c02c34dc4669b6bd1e18a027ff75b53b5:CompileXIB
>   /Users/dev/git/proj/Resources/Controllers/Controller.xib' and
>   'adf8a93da84709e14beaf35ec6d6d21c02c34dc4669b6bd1e18a027ff75b53b5:CompileXIB
>   /Users/dev/git/proj/Resources/Controllers/Controller~ipad.xib')

Should I rename them or is there another solution?

Comment: I encounter the same issue with a regular html localised file. Did you find a cause?

Comment: @Lukasz, it is a known issue listed in Xcode release notes, so I guess Apple engineers are working on it. In my case, I just renamed my XIB files.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a known bug in Xcode 9 beta. There is no workaround for the moment.

"XIB and Storyboard files which use platform-specific naming conventions (e.g. “MyView~ipad.xib”) may cause the new build system to emit an “unable to build node” error. (32409101)"

So YES, you can try to remove the "~ipad" and just execute it on iPad simulator.

Open radar: [New Build System fails to build project containing universal xib](http://www.openradar.me/32675858)